# Finding the number of nodes at each level during bfs

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, tree, breadth-first-search

You have been given a Tree consisting of N nodes. A tree is a fully-connected graph consisting of N nodes and N−1 edges. The nodes in this tree are indexed from 1 to N. Consider node indexed 1 to be the root node of this tree. The root node lies at level one in the tree. You shall be given the tree and a single integer x . You need to find out the number of nodes lying on level x.

Input Format

The first line consists of a single integer N denoting the number of nodes in the tree. Each of the next n−1 lines consists of 2 integers a andb denoting an undirected edge between node a and node b. The next line consists of a single integer x.

Output Format

You need to print a single integers denoting the number of nodes on level x.

---

below is the code snippet i wrote and its not correct. Please help me find the error.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LevelNodes {
    public static ArrayList[] adj;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = sc.nextInt();
        boolean[] visites = new boolean[N];
        ArrayList[] adj = new ArrayList[N];
        for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
            adj[j] = new ArrayList();
        }
        for(int i = 0;i < (N-1) ;i++){
            int a = sc.nextInt();
            int b = sc.nextInt();
            adj[a-1].add(b);
            adj[b-1].add(a);
        }
        int level = sc.nextInt();
        int counter = 0;
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
        list.add(1);
        counter++;
        while(!list.isEmpty()){
            int n = (Integer) list.poll();
            for(int x = 0; x< adj[n-1].size();x++){
                list.add(adj[n-1].get(x));
            }
            counter++;
            if(counter == level){
                System.out.println(list.size());
                break;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @Vivek and welcome to SO! Have you tried to debug your code? Where do you think is the problem? What is the current behavior you get and why is it incorrect?

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: You might want to add `if (level <= 0 || N <= level) { System.out.println("0"); System.exit(0); }` and similar when `counter` never equals `level`.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: The [How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems in your code:

The first problem is that your code might not terminate. This is because you are adding both edges u->v and v->u to your adjacency list. So whenever you poll u from the list and add its neighbors, you are going to add v to the list. Likewise, whenever you poll v and add its neighbors, you are going to add back u to the list. You need to maintain a boolean array `visited` and set `visited[u]=true` whenever you add u to the list. This way you can add only unvisited nodes to your scan list.

Another major problem is in the while loop. You are incrementing the level counter variable `counter++;` whenever you visit a new node. Consider the tree below and assume we need to find the number of nodes at level 2 (the last level).

```
     1
    / \
   2   3
  / \ / \
 4  5 6  7
```

Initially your list contains 1 and `counter=1`. In the first iteration, you poll 1 from the list and add its neighbors: 2 and 3. At this stage, `counter=2`. In the next two iterations, you are going to remove 2 then 3 from the list, add their neighbors, and increment `counter` each time. So by the time you reach the second level, `counter` would be equal to 4. The If statement would never be executed.

To fix this, you have to increment `counter` iff you are done processing all the node at the current level. A simple (untested) way to do that is to use a second temporary list to hold the neighbors of all the nodes at the current level. Then, whenever the original list is empty, you know that you have processed all the nodes at the current level. Here, you increment `counter` and move all the nodes from the temporary list to the main list.

```
while(!list.isEmpty()){
    int n = (Integer) list.poll();
    for(int x = 0; x< adj[n-1].size();x++){
        tmpList.add(adj[n-1].get(x));
    }

    if(list.isEmpty()) {
        if(counter == level){
            System.out.println(tmpList.size());
            break;
        }

        list.addAll(tmpList);
        tmpList.clear();
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: (I'd probably use `current` and `next` instead of `list` and `tmpList`, and `current = next; next = new ListImpl();` to advance to the next level. And practice using `Stream`s, if not "foreach-loops" instead of `poll`ing. Most definitely, I'd start with (doc)comments.)